# Confused with the android build target settings terminologies

Tags: android, eclipse, android-build, android-buildconfig

I went through the different explanations of different terms for android settings, but still am confused for my particular case.

I have a specific query for my case. Earlier I had following settings for my android library eclipse project:

```
    Project Build Target : API Level 15
    Project.properties file : target=android-15
    Manifest.xml : 
       minSDKVersion : 15
       targetSDKVersion : 15
```

This allowed the library to support Android 4.0.3 and above.

Now, I have done some changes in my library and specifically have used - `@JavascriptInterface` and `Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT`

Now I have following values for my library:

```
    Project Build Target : API Level 19
    Project.properties file : target=android-19
    Manifest.xml : 
       minSDKVersion : 15
       targetSDKVersion : 15
```

Will this still allow me to use the library on all devices without problems from Android 4.0.3 and above?

If not, can someone please advice while using the above changes how can I still maintain support Android 4.0.3 onwards?

Comment: `minSDKVersion : 15
       targetSDKVersion : 19`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya does that mean that the target settings in project.properties file does not affect - on which devices the library can be used?

Comment: If my Answer helped you, can you please choose it as a correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your target build and compile version should always be same and it has to be the latest version or to the highest API version that you have. Because New API version might not have old libraries or say some libraries are deprecated in the newer version. So better target the latest version or highest version you have.